# npm install, nodered, sensortag

Tags: node.js, npm, intel-edison

I have an Intel Edison connected via SSH to my computer. I used putty to run nodered and then send the sensor information forward. At first, when i used npm install, i got the error messages shown in  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsDqBeUrRD5oYqdUFVrCJ1-cTKAli2Se/view?usp=sharing I was able to install nodered in the older version 0.9.1. but when trying to add nodes / libraries using npm install I saw "npm: command not found". now when i use npm -v i also see "npm: command not found". When i use node -v it gets the version info. Please help install npm on my intel edison. I need this to install nodes / libraries for sensortag and google sheet.

Yours faithfully

Comment: Are you using stock image on Edison or a newer one from community (https://github.com/edison-fw/)?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the stock image is too old. [github.com/edison-fw](https://github.com/edison-fw) is on Yocto Poky version Dunfell. I have already moved on to Gatesgarth, which is already working nicely but not yet ready for prime time. Nevertheless:

```
    root@yuna:~# node -v
    v12.20.1

    root@yuna:~# npm -v i
    6.14.10
```

Now looking at the first line in your log:

```
root@edison:~# npm install --unsafe-perm node-red
npm WARN engine node-red@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current:
{"node":"4.4.3" ,"npm":"2.15.1"})
```

edison-fw also has ready images if you don't want to build your self.